# Symfony 2.7 Route on top of class

Tags: symfony-2.3

I would like to ask you about routing in symfony. I know that we can put a route on top of action but I saw a way when putting route on top of class. I want to know what this means? cos when I'm putting route on top of class I'm getting page not found error.

```
    <?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Class DefaultController
 * @package AppBundle\Controller
 * @Route('/Test')
 */
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {

        // replace this example code with whatever you need
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig', array(
            'base_dir' => realpath($this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir').'/..'),
        ));

    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you put a Route on the top of a class AND on the action: symfony append the second to the first: 
eg: on the top class @Route("a/b"), on the action @Route('/c/d')
then then the action path is : a/b/c/d 
But a route only on the class can not work

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem is that I'm getting 404 Not Found error when in showed case I'm locating http://localhost/test/web/app.php/Test/

Comment: add something in the action route @Route('/my-action') , then check:
localhost/test/web/app.php/Test/my-action

Comment: Sorry but not working. May be I'm doing something wrong. Thanks.

Comment: localhost/test/web/app.php/Test/  <--that slash may cause a problem if you forget it.
and try to avoid route with only a slash, Sf may get confused

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The annotation **@Route** can work both in Methods and in Classes.

A controller should wrap always methods related by the same topic, for example, CartController. Inside this controller you will have Cart-related methods, so you should be able to define some kind of prefix for all of them.

so, if you have **@Route("/cart")**, each method's route defined with that annotation will be appended to this prefix */cart*. Remember, appended doesn't mean overwritten.

That should work.

Your *"Page not found"* message has nothing to do with this annotation :)

### **UPDATE**

Some steps to check that your route is being loaded.

- Symfony brings you a router debugger. It lists you all found and available routes from your project. From the root of your project, `php app/console debug:route`. For Symfony 3.*, `php bin/console debug:router` and for very old Symfony versions... `php app/console router:debug`.
- If the route is not there, make sure that your routes are being loaded. You need to specify to the Framework that your controller needs to be parsed in order to find **@Route** annotations :)

Check how to load routes from annotations in many ways [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html)

The easy way is...

```
app:
    resource: "@AppBundle/Controller"
    type:     annotation
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But why I'm not able to open the page, may be I need to relate in somewhere?

Comment: First of all, make sure that your route is being loaded. Do php app/console debug:router. Is your route appearing?

Comment: Updated the main answer :)

Comment: Thanks. I have checked it there is a route in list of routes. But cannot open the page.